# Saving an express-session in socket.io

Tags: express, session, socket.io, express-session

I can not understand why my sessions do not want to be saved.

Each time I connect, I get a new session id, but if I just go (through the browser) to tessocket.local, the session is saved and already when called through the socket, it is normally determined. That's actually the question - how to defeat it?

Forcing the session to be saved after `io.on("connection"` doesn't help.

If you remove `transports: ["websocket"`] - polling starts working, but then the session is not defined at all through the socket.

client.js

```
const socketOptions =  {

    "force new connection" : true,
    "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
    "timeout" : 10000,
    "transports" : ["websocket"]
};
// @ts-ignore
socket = io('https://tessocket.local',socketOptions)
 // @ts-ignore
socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
    console.log(event, args);
  });
return socket
```

server.js

```
 const app = require('express')(),
  http = require('http'),
  https = require('https'),
  // http  = require("http"),
  fs = require( "fs" ),
  path = require("path"),
  eSession = require("express-session"),
  MongoDBStore = require('express-mongodb-session')(eSession),
  store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: 'mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/tmp?authSource=admin',
    collection: 'sessions'
  });
 
 
    options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../minica/test.local/key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../minica/test.local/cert.pem")),
    },
    server =  https.createServer(options, app)

  const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: "http://test.local:3000",
    transports: ["websocket"]
  }),
  session = eSession({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false, // key
      maxAge: null,
      path: "/",
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none'
    },
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");


// Attach session
app.use(session);

// Share session with io sockets

io.use(sharedsession(session));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    // Accept a login event with user's data
    console.log(socket.handshake.session.id) 
    socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
    });
    socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
        if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
            delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
            socket.handshake.session.save();
        }
    });        
});

server.listen(443);
```

socket.io@4.4.1

express@4

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Sessions are saved using the cookie header, which is not avaliable when using a ws protocol afaik.

Comment: you forgot to configure cookie in ws config it should look like this  ```const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://test.local:3000',
    credentials: true,
  },
})
``` 
and in client side add ```withCredentials: true``` to `socketOptions` object 

now you can access cookie (raw)  in server like this ```const rawCookies = socket.handshake.headers.cookie || socket.request.headers.cookie
```